Javafx TreeView strange selection behavior
I try to take care that the user who selects a TreeView item by mouse click or by key press does not choose a container item. Pressing the arrow keys you go up and down the leaf items only. A mouse click on a container item selects its first leaf.
My data are very simple. There are simple String containers, and each container does have one or more leaves.
My code is as follows:
package volker.treeviewtest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModel;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setStyle("-fx-font-family: Helvetica");
        
        Label label = new Label();
        
        TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<>("Root");
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        TreeItem<String> bough = new TreeItem<>("Bough");
        bough.setExpanded(true);
        bough.getChildren().addAll(
                new TreeItem<>("Bud"),
                new TreeItem<>("Buddy"));

        TreeItem<String> twig =
                new TreeItem<>("Twig");
        twig.setExpanded(true);
        twig.getChildren().addAll(
                new TreeItem<>("Tic"),
                new TreeItem<>("Tac"),
                new TreeItem<>("Toe"));

        TreeItem<String> twiggy =
                new TreeItem<>("Twiggy");
        twiggy.setExpanded(true);
        twiggy.getChildren().addAll(
                new TreeItem<>("Ene"),
                new TreeItem<>("Mene"),
                new TreeItem<>("Muh"));

        bough.getChildren().addAll(twig, twiggy);

        rootItem.getChildren().add(bough);

        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(rootItem);
        treeView.setShowRoot(false);
        
        MultipleSelectionModel<TreeItem<String>> selModel =
                treeView.getSelectionModel();
        selModel.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        selModel.selectIndices(1);
        
        selModel.selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            TreeItem<String> newSelection = newVal;
            if (!newSelection.isLeaf()) {
                if (!newSelection.isExpanded()) {
                    newSelection.setExpanded(true);
                }
                TreeItem<String> firstLeaf = newSelection.getChildren().get(0);
                if (firstLeaf.equals(oldVal)) {
                    // From first leaf of current container
                    // to last leaf of previous container
                    TreeItem<String> prev = newSelection.previousSibling();
                    if (prev == null) {
                        newSelection = oldVal;
                    } else if (prev.isLeaf()) {
                        newSelection = prev;
                    } else {
                        prev.setExpanded(true);
                        int size = prev.getChildren().size();
                        TreeItem lastLeaf = prev.getChildren().get(size - 1);
                        newSelection = lastLeaf;
                    }
                } else {
                    newSelection = firstLeaf;
                }
            }
            selModel.select(newSelection);
            label.setText(newSelection.getValue());
        });
        
        root.getChildren().addAll(treeView, label);
        
        var scene = new Scene(root, 150, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}

It works as intended. But... e.g. I click on the "Ene" item and then click on the triangle to set the "Twig" container collapsed. Then then press the up arrow key (or click on the "Twiggy" container) and I find that "Twig" is expanded with its last leaf selected as intended (blue background), but "Twiggy" gets a blue border and another press on the up arrow key doesn't change anything. The selection listener doesn't fire.
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/82eYjcJT.png)
That's not a big thing as a press on the down arrow followed by the up arrow (or a mouse click somewhere) ends this queer behavior. But I'm curious to learn why this happens and what I can do to prevent it. Is there a better way to achieve my aim?
I know the question 31267157, but it doesn't seem to help me.

Generally in JavaFX you should not change a property in a listener for that property, either indirectly or directly. This (arguably) is something of an arbitrary rule that is a product of nothing other than the implementation of properties and listener notification, but it is what it is. You violate this rule by calling selModel.select(...) in the listener for the selected item, so the behavior is likely to be somewhat unpredictable. You could try implementing a custom selection model, though that is something of a big task.

As a hack, you can try wrapping the change of selection (and the text of the label) in Platform.runLater(...), ensuring that happens after the current processing of the selection change is complete.

It's still a hack though. If you put a listener on the selectedProperty() you will see it register the "invalid" selections before reverting to the valid ones. A custom selection model, which you could implement the same way as in the post you referenced, would avoid this.

You can answer your own question to indicate that it is solved.

Thanks to James_D: I'll give it a try.

Generally in JavaFX you should not change a property in a listener for that property, either indirectly or directly. This (arguably) is something of an arbitrary rule that is a product of nothing other than the implementation of properties and listener notification, but it is what it is. You violate this rule by calling selModel.select(...) in the listener for the selected item, so the behavior is likely to be somewhat unpredictable.
The best way to implement this is to implement your own selection model, following the example you already referenced. Unfortunately this is something of a difficult task, but a prototype might look like this:

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModel;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setStyle("-fx-font-family: Helvetica");

        Label label = new Label();

        TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<>("Root");
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        TreeItem<String> bough = new TreeItem<>("Bough");
        bough.setExpanded(true);
        bough.getChildren().addAll(
                new TreeItem<>("Bud"),
                new TreeItem<>("Buddy"));

        TreeItem<String> twig =
                new TreeItem<>("Twig");
        twig.setExpanded(true);
        twig.getChildren().addAll(
                new TreeItem<>("Tic"),
                new TreeItem<>("Tac"),
                new TreeItem<>("Toe"));

        TreeItem<String> twiggy =
                new TreeItem<>("Twiggy");
        twiggy.setExpanded(true);
        twiggy.getChildren().addAll(
                new TreeItem<>("Ene"),
                new TreeItem<>("Mene"),
                new TreeItem<>("Muh"));

        bough.getChildren().addAll(twig, twiggy);

        rootItem.getChildren().add(bough);

        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(rootItem);
        treeView.setShowRoot(false);

        MultipleSelectionModel<TreeItem<String>> selModel =
                treeView.getSelectionModel();
        selModel.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);

        MultipleSelectionModel<TreeItem<String>> modifiedSelectionModel = new MultipleSelectionModel<TreeItem<String>>() {

            private TreeItem<String> lastSelection = null ;
            @Override
            public ObservableList<Integer> getSelectedIndices() {
                return selModel.getSelectedIndices();
            }

            @Override
            public ObservableList<TreeItem<String>> getSelectedItems() {
                return selModel.getSelectedItems();
            }

            @Override
            public void selectIndices(int i, int... ints) {
                select(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void selectAll() {
                select(0);
            }

            @Override
            public void selectFirst() {
                select(0);
            }

            @Override
            public void selectLast() {
                select(treeView.getExpandedItemCount()-1);
            }

            @Override
            public void clearAndSelect(int i) {
                clearSelection();
                select(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void select(int i) {
                if (i >= 0 && i < treeView.getExpandedItemCount()) {
                    select(treeView.getTreeItem(i));
                } else {
                    select(null);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void select(TreeItem<String> stringTreeItem) {
                if (stringTreeItem == null) {
                    clearSelection();
                } else {
                    if (stringTreeItem.isLeaf()) {
                        selModel.select(stringTreeItem);
                    } else {
                        stringTreeItem.setExpanded(true);
                        TreeItem<String> firstChild = stringTreeItem.getChildren().get(0);
                        if (firstChild.equals(lastSelection)) {
                            TreeItem<String> prev = stringTreeItem.previousSibling();
                            if (prev.isLeaf()) {
                                selModel.select(prev);
                            } else {
                                prev.setExpanded(true);
                                int lastIndex = prev.getChildren().size() - 1 ;
                                selModel.select(prev.getChildren().get(lastIndex));
                            }
                        } else {
                            select(firstChild);
                        }
                    }
                }
                lastSelection = selModel.getSelectedItem();
            }

            @Override
            public void clearSelection(int i) {
                selModel.clearSelection(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void clearSelection() {
                selModel.clearSelection();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isSelected(int i) {
                return selModel.isSelected(i);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEmpty() {
                return selModel.isEmpty();
            }

            @Override
            public void selectPrevious() {
                select(getSelectedIndex() - 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void selectNext() {
                select(getSelectedIndex() + 1);
            }
        };

        treeView.setSelectionModel(modifiedSelectionModel);

        modifiedSelectionModel.selectIndices(1);
        
        modifiedSelectionModel.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        modifiedSelectionModel.selectedItemProperty().addListener((_, oldSel, newSel) -> System.out.printf("Selection changed from %s to %s%n", oldSel.getValue(), newSel.getValue()));

        root.getChildren().addAll(treeView, label);

        var scene = new Scene(root, 150, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}

A more robust solution may be available (for example, this really only handles single selection) but this should at a minimum get you started.
If you want a quick hack, you can simply wrap the update to the existing selection model in your listener in a Platform.runLater(...). This will ensure the change requested is processed before you modify the change:
        selModel.selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            // ...
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                selModel.select(newSelection);
                label.setText(newSelection.getValue());
            });
        });

This is a hack though, because listeners on your selection model will observe invalid selections before seeing the correct selection, which may cause you problems.

Wow. Is this (not the hack) state of the art or simply genial? I needed only a few minor changes to get it all done. Thank you.

@volkerpeter The selection model is the object that manages selection, so if you want to modify selection logic in a control, using a custom selection model is the sensible way to do it. In my opinion, it would be a bit more convenient if the library provided some concrete extensible classes to work from, instead of having to implement the interface from scratch, but as you can see it's not too difficult.

I was impressed by the idea to use two selection models.

@volkerpeter That is a standard pattern (the "Decorator pattern" or "Wrapper class") to implement an interface when you already have an implementation doing most of what you want.

The hack suggested by James_D works for me:
        selModel.selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
        if (!newVal.isLeaf()) {
            if (!newVal.isExpanded()) {
                newVal.setExpanded(true);
            }
            TreeItem<String> firstLeaf = newVal.getChildren().get(0);
            if (firstLeaf.equals(oldVal)) {
                // From first leaf of current container
                // to last leaf of previous container
                TreeItem<String> prev = newVal.previousSibling();
                if (prev == null) {
                    newVal = oldVal;
                } else if (prev.isLeaf()) {
                    newVal = prev;
                } else {
                    prev.setExpanded(true);
                    int size = prev.getChildren().size();
                    TreeItem lastLeaf = prev.getChildren().get(size - 1);
                    newVal = lastLeaf;
                }
            } else {
                newVal = firstLeaf;
            }
        }
        TreeItem<String> newSelection = newVal;
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            selModel.select(newSelection);
            label.setText(newSelection.getValue());
        });
    });

